# Access address of pointer in pointer-to-pointer array

Tags: c, pointers, char

4I am trying to get a pointer address from a pointer to a pointer array, however I just get garbage when I run the code below. How do I retrieve the pointer address of one of the char * from the char ** array? Thanks for checking this out.

Specifically, I want to obtain the address of "wh" via "what" and assign it to "hi".

```
char * hi;
char * wh;
char ** what;

int main(void) {
    char z[4] = "wx\0";
    char a[4] = "ab\0";
    hi = &z;
    wh = &a;
    what = (char **) malloc( 25 * sizeof(char));
    what[0] = &hi;
    what[1] = &wh;

    printf("%s | %s\n", hi, wh);

    hi = &what[1];

    printf("%s | %s\n", hi, wh);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: When you say "pointer address", do you mean the address of the pointer itself, or the address it's pointing to?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, the address it is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression the string terminator \0 was one character. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Also your call is *very* strange.

Comment: When you call malloc, it returns a char*. Why are you casting it to char**? Also, call calloc(), not malloc(), for allocating contiguous memory chunks like "25 chars".

Comment: @Sukminder: `z` and `a` are (were, before the edit) three bytes, because they are defined as arrays of three `char`. Initializing them with a string literal containing three explicit characters and one implicit null character is legal. The implicit terminating null is ignored.

Comment: @Justin3o9 `'\0'` is indeed a single character, but you have `char z[4]` and that `4` won't be forgotten.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What? The arrays have `[4]`.

Comment: @unwind: The question was edited.

Comment: @ZachStark Wrong, the return type of `malloc()` is `void *`. And of course the memory returned from `malloc()` is just as "contiguous" as that which `calloc()` returns.

Comment: @unwind My point still stands; it returns a single pointer rather than a double pointer that it is being explicitly cast to.

Comment: @ZachStark That was hardly the way you stated it, though. :) There's a *huge* amount of confusion around here about the return type of `malloc()` and how to deal with `void *` in C, and making it worse is very counter-productive in my opinion.

Comment: @ZachStark, the return from malloc can converted to a pointer to any type, including a pointer type. Thus assigning the return from malloc to a `char **` is perfectly legitimate. The cast is unnecessary, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char * hi;
char * wh;
char ** what;

int main(void) {
    char z[3] = "wx\0";
    char a[3] = "ab\0";
    hi = z;
    wh = a;
    what = malloc(2 * sizeof *what);
    what[0] = hi;
    what[1] = wh;

    printf("%s | %s\n", hi, wh);

    hi = what[1];

    printf("%s | %s\n", hi, wh);

    return 0;
}
```

The type of `hi` and `wh` is not the same as of `&z` and `&a`, even though they should yield the same value. Also you want `what[1]` in `hi` not the value of the memory location where it is. Also, in C you do not need to cast the return of malloc. However,  in C++ the cast is required although its better to use the `new` operator.

Comment: This `what = (char **) malloc( 25 * sizeof(char))` is broken, or at least misleading. So, the code is not yet "corrected". As usual, using type names under `sizeof` and casting result of `malloc` is a recipe for errors. Should be `what = malloc(25 * sizeof *what)`.

Comment: `malloc()` should be modified to allocate for `char *`'s

Comment: I see that Acme has edited to the One True(TM) form of `malloc()`, great!

Answer (score 2):

### Pointer Assignment

- `hi` and `wh` are defined as *pointer to char*.  So, change your assignment statements

  from,

  ```
  hi = &z; /* Type of &z is pointer-to-array-of-4-char */
  wh = &a; /* Type of &a is pointer-to-array-of-4-char */
  ```

  to,

  ```
  hi = z; /* Type of z is pointer-to-char. Array name, here, decays into pointer 
             to first element of the array */
  wh = a; /* Type of a is pointer-to-char */
  ```

  ---
- `what` is defined as type,  *pointer to pointer to char*. So, change your `malloc` statement

  from,

  ```
  what = (char **) malloc( 25 * sizeof(char)); /* what needs to hold char*'s, 
                                                  you have allocated only for char's */
  ```

  to,

  ```
  what = malloc(25 * sizeof *what); /* what is of type char**. *what gives you char* */
  ```

  ---
- Also, change your `what` , `hi` assignment statements

  from,

  ```
  what[0] = &hi; /* Type of what[0] is pointer-to-char;
                    Type of &hi is pointer-to-pointer-to-char */
  what[1] = &wh; /* Type of what[1] is pointer-to-char;
                    Type of &wh is pointer-to-pointer-to-char */
  ...
  hi = &what[1]; /* Type of hi is pointer-to-char;
                    Type of &what[1] is pointer-to-pointer-to-char */
  ```

  to ,

  ```
  what[0] = hi; /* Types are same */
  what[1] = wh; /* Types are same */
  ...
  hi = what[1]; /* Types are same */
  ```

  ---

**Note:**
The size of `what` is too high than what really required for the posted program. If you feel, you are going to have the same program, modify `25` to `2` in the `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * hi;
char * wh;
char ** what;

int main(void) {
    char z[4] = "wx\0";
    char a[4] = "ab\0";
    hi = &z;
    wh = &a;
```

First mistake; the types of the expressions `&z` and `&a` are both `char (*)[4]` (pointer to 4-element array of `char`), not `char *`.  To fix this, drop the `&` from both:

```
    hi = z;
    wh = a;
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element in the array.

```
    what = (char **) malloc( 25 * sizeof(char));
```

Don't cast the result of `malloc`; it isn't necessary<sup>1</sup>, and depending on the compiler version it can suppress a useful diagnostic.  You also have a type mismatch.  You want to space for 25 pointers to `char`, but you're only allocating enough for 25 plain `char`s.  Rewrite that as

```
    what = malloc( sizeof *what * 25 );
```

The type of the expression `what` is `char **`; thus, the type of the expression `*what` is `char *`.  So `sizeof *what` will give you the same result as `sizeof (char *)`.  The above line allocates enough memory to store 25 pointers to `char`, and assigns the resulting pointer to `what`.

```
    what[0] = &hi;
    what[1] = &wh;
```

Again, drop the `&`; `hi` and `wh` are already pointers to `char`:

```
    what[0] = hi;
    what[1] = wh;

    printf("%s | %s\n", hi, wh);

    hi = &what[1];
```

Type mismatch; `&what[1]` has type `char **`, `hi` has type `char *`.  Again, drop the `&`.

```
    hi = what[1];
```

`hi` and `wh` now point to the same thing (`what[1]` == `wh` and `hi` == `what[1]`, so `hi` == `wh`; that is, both `hi` and `wh` contain the same pointer value).

```
    printf("%s | %s\n", hi, wh);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

---

<sup>1.  In C, that is; C++ is a different story, but if you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway.</sup>